# Spring, Multi module application context, B depends on A but cannot see bean

Tags: java, spring

should the following application context load all bean definitions across the different *-context.xml before initializing beans? I'm finding that one of my classes can't find a 
dependant bean unless i mark it as lazy-init so the bean gets a chance to load. However i thought that the entire context is read before initializing any beans.

Also, This could be something to do with multiple config locations as opposed to bean imports using the `<import.../>` tag

My structure is as follows:

```
APP.ear
|-- utilJars
|   |-- A.jar
|   |-- A-API.jar
|   |-- B.jar
|   |-- B-API.jar
|   `-- CONTROL.jar
`-- WEB.war
```

- A-API.jar contains a service interface called MyService
- A.jar contains a context.xml with the MyServiceImpl bean declaration
- B-API.jar contains a service interface called MyOtherService
- B.jar depends on A-API.jar + B-API.jar
- B.jar contains a context.xml with the MyOtherServiceImpl that depends on the timeService to be autowired.
- CONTROL.jar depends on all other utilJars.
- CONTROL.jar contains a beanRefContext.xml that defines a ClassPathXmlApplicationContext with the given contstructor Args:

.

```
<!-- in CONTROL.jar -->
<bean id="ear.context" class="org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <value>classpath*:META-INF/**/*-context.xml</value>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

- WEB.war contains the AppInitializer that declares the `parentContextKey` with the value `classpath:META-INF/beanRefContext.xml`

When I start the application, I get the following message during Initialization:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.access.BootstrapException: Unable to initialize group definition. Group resource name [classpath:META-INF/beanRefContext.xml], factory key [ear.context]; 
`-> nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ear.context' defined in class path resource [META-INF/beanRefContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; 
`-> nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext]: Constructor threw exception; 
`-> nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'myService' is defined.
```

Can someone please help me understand how the configuration and instantiation of spring app contexts work so i can solve this murder?

**UPDATE:** [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#resources-classpath-wildcards) states:

> When constructing an XML-based application context, a location string may use the special classpath*: prefix:
>
> `ApplicationContext ctx =
>       new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:conf/appContext.xml");`
>
> This special prefix specifies that all classpath resources that match the given name must be obtained (internally, this essentially happens via a ClassLoader.getResources(...) call), and then **merged to form the final application** context definition.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A.jar had no manifest entry for A-API.jar so could not see the interface.